# RxJS grouping emitted events nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable

I'm am querying a database and retrieving the results as a row by row stream of events 'db_row_receieved'. I am trying to group these results by company Id, but I am getting no output on the subscription.

The db row format is shown below.

```
 // row 1
    {
        companyId: 50,
        value: 200
    }
    // row 2   
    {
        companyId: 50,
        value: 300
    }
    // row 3 
    {
        companyId: 51,
        value: 400
    }
```

Code:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'db_row_receieved');
var grouped = source.groupBy((x) => { return x.companyId; });
var selectMany = grouped.selectMany(x => x.reduce((acc, v) => {
                             return acc + v.value;
                          }, 0));

var subscription = selectMany.subscribe(function (obs) {
                        console.log("value: ", obs);
                   }
```

Expected output:

```
value: 500    // from the group with companyId 50
value: 400    // from the group with companyId 51
```

Actual output:
    subscription not outputting anything, but works when using Rx.Observable.fromArray(someArray)

Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: Are you sure `eventEmitter` is actually emitting events with the given name. The rest of the code looks ok.

Comment: Did you try grouped.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); }); to see if the groupeBy works

Comment: @Yury, Yes, eventEmitter does emit a row.

Comment: @oliv37 Yes the group by works. I beginning to think its an issue grouping a hot observable

Comment: can you add a console.log into your reduce function eg : { console.log(acc); return acc + v.value; }. I think it doesn't work because it doesn't know what is the final event. That would explain why it works with an array

Comment: @user1145347 It won't deliver results until the last event. Imagine your emitter emits 'company1', 'company1', 'company2', 'company1', 'company2' how namy groups do you expect?

Comment: @Yury About 6 million groups, but I'm testing with 3 groups for now. I will put those logs in. It should give a better understanding of whats happening. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: @user1145347 I mean how many groups for this scenario ( 'company1', 'company1', 'company2', 'company1', 'company2') is it 2 or 4?

Comment: @Yuri 2 groups, first group (companyId = 50) and second group (companyId = 51)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that `reduce` will produce a single value only if the underlying stream `complete`d. Since an event emitter is sort of infinite source it is always active.

Take a look at the snippet below - the first example completes, the other does not.

```js
const data = [
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
  {k: 'B', v: 10},
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
  {k: 'B', v: 10},
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
  {k: 'B', v: 10},
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
  {k: 'A', v: 1},
];

Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .concatMap(d => Rx.Observable.of(d).delay(100))
  .groupBy(d => d.k)
  .mergeMap(group => group.reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc.sum += value.v;
    return acc;
  }, {key: group.key, sum: 0}))
  .do(d => console.log('RESULT', d.key, d.sum))
  .subscribe();
  
Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .concatMap(d => Rx.Observable.of(d).delay(100))
  .merge(Rx.Observable.never()) // MERGIN NEVER IN
  // .take(data.length) // UNCOMMENT TO MITIGATE NEVER
  .groupBy(d => d.k)
  .mergeMap(group => group.reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc.sum += value.v;
    return acc;
  }, {key: group.key, sum: 0}))
  .do(d => console.log('RESULT - NEVER - WILL NOT BE PRINTED', d))
  .subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.10/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

I do not know your specific use case but 2 most common thing that comes to mind are:

- use `scan` (probably with debounce),
- use `takeUntil` if there is an event which indicates the end of underling stream.